# Apostrophe removing characters in help in schema when using a pipe

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a field schema in a piece I am creating. Adding a a help value to it with a pipe in it removes all text before the pipe.

e.g.

```
{
  name: 'text_example'
  type: 'string',
  help: 'Key value pairs, e.g. key|value',
  textarea: true
}
```

results in the help text on the field showing "value"

Is it being laundered? Does it need to be? I have tried all types of ways to trying to get it to work, adding escape characters \ using html and ascii codes. Usng String.fromCharCode(124). Nothing allows a pipe in the text.

Answer (score 0):

The `help` string is being run through the i18n module, which has known issues around the pipe character.

A workaround is to use `htmlHelp` property instead of the standard `help` field property and to escape the pipe like this

```
 {
  name: 'test',
  label: 'Test',
  htmlHelp: 'Extending this logic, the chive of \&#124; a rocket becomes an undamped wholesaler.',
  type: 'string'
 }
```

This gets run through Nunjucks `safe` filter which translates the entity.